# Sending float from Python to C# over socket

Tags: python, c#, sockets, byte

I am calculating a float value in Python and I want to send it back to my C# application.

So in Python I convert my float to a bytearray and send it like this:

```
flaotToByte = struct.pack('!d', myFloat)
conn.send(flaotToByte)
```

On my C# client side, I receive the bytearray and want to convert it back to float:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[100];
int idxUsedBytes = client.Receive(bytes);
float res = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);
```

When I print the float in Python before converting, it looks like this:

```
0.003890838631358603
```

But on my client's side, my float currently is this one:

```
-0.000000000101606
```

This feels like it should be super basic, but I can't figure out why this is not working. For testing, I converted my bytearray back to float directly in Python and I got this result:

```
print(struct.unpack('!d', floatToByte))
>>>(0.003890838631358603,)
```

So maybe something is wrong on my Python side?

Comment: In C#, a `float` is 32 bits. I think in Python it depends on the implementation but it can definitely exceed 32 bits so I don't think `float` (`Single`) is what you want your client to be using

Comment: You are receiving 4 bytes for a float.  Did you misspell float : flaotToByte

Comment: @jdweng Oh, sorry, only in this post! So that means, theoretically, if everything was correct, this should work if my byte buffer had the size of 4? Because then I would receive exactly one float and could convert it?

Comment: As long as the order of the bytes are the same.  Some times you get Bid?Little Endian issues is the bytes are not in the correct order for windows.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, it is possible to send the float value as string? And parse it on C#?